# Avoiding performance concerns of Runtime Polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop

In a numerical code run on thousands of processors for 10s of hours, I have a base class (Mesh) whose methods are hit 100s to 1000s of millions of times. There are currently two (Mesh_A, Mesh_B) derived classes, but eventually this will expand to three or four.  User code cannot know until runtime whether its pointer to Mesh is actually a Mesh_A or Mesh_B, but for the rest of the run, it never changes.

**Current Implementation:**

```
// Base class
class Mesh {
  ...
  virtual const Point& cell_centroid(int c) = 0;
}

// derived class A
class MeshA : public Mesh {
  ...
  Point& cell_centroid(int c) { return cell_centroids_[c]; }
}

// derived class B
class MeshB : public Mesh {
  ...
  Point& cell_centroid(int c) { return other_framework_->cell_centroid(c); }
}


// typical user class
class User {
  User(Mesh* mesh) : mesh_(mesh) {}

  void evalFunction() {
    for (int c=0; c!=mesh_->num_cells(); ++c) {
      double result = func(mesh_->cell_centroid(c));
      ...
    }
  }


  // Other methods which use mesh_->cell_centroid() very often, and in different ways.
}
```

Previously, MeshA was the only Mesh, and there was no base class, and the heavily hit methods were all inlined.  Profiling shows that the change to runtime polymorphism (likely thanks to the loss of inlining?) with virtual methods has resulted in a ~15% hit, which just isn't going to fly.

I've been pouring over static polymorphism and other ideas, but I'd love to hear thoughts on how one might avoid this hit in a reasonably sustainable way.

**Idea 1:** Coarsen the virtual function to amortize overhead.  One thought was to try to encapsulate all the "calling patterns" of these methods inside a virtual method, lifting the virtual to a coarser level while keeping the fine-grained methods as non-virtual.  For example, in the above example, one could pass a function pointer to a new virtual method of Mesh that implemented the loop, returning an array of doubles and called a non-virtual, inlined cell_centroid() method inside of this.

```
// Base class
class Mesh {
  ...
  virtual void evalFunction(double (*func)(Point&), std::vector<double>* result) = 0;
}

// derived class A
class MeshA : public Mesh {
  ...

  void evalFunction(double (*func)(Point&), std::vector<double>* result) {
    for (int c=0; c!=num_cells(); ++c) (*result)[c] = (*func)(cell_centroid(c));
  }

  Point& cell_centroid(int c) { return cell_centroids_[c]; }
}

// similar for B


// typical user class
class User {
  User(Mesh* mesh) : mesh_(mesh) {}

  void evalFunction() {
    m_->evalFunction();
  }
}
```

I'm a little nervous that this will make the Mesh interface huge -- I don't have a single access pattern (like the example) that could easily be encapsulated.  My guess is that, for every virtual method in the current Mesh class (15-20), I'd have 3 or 4 different "calling patterns", and the interface for Mesh would explode.  There are a variety of "User" classes and, while the sometimes use Mesh the same way, they don't always, and I don't want to limit myself to a few patterns.

**Idea 2:** Template all user code with `Mesh_T`.  Write a factory that creates `User<MeshA>` or `User<MeshB>` instances depending upon runtime information.  This is a little concerning because this will effectively mean that my entire code is templated code, compile times will blow up, errors will be harder to debug etc.  A large code base would be touched.

**Idea 3:** It seems to me that one ought to be able to resolve, at the start of the run, that the Mesh pointer User gets is actually a MeshA or MeshB, and not need to do the virtual table lookups and regain the inlined A or B implementation.  I don't know of an elegant way of doing this that wouldn't basically be worse than Idea 1, i.e. a bunch of duplicated code in User with case/switch.  But if there were an elegant way of doing this, it would be my first choice.

Any thoughts on a good choice, a better idea, or other comments on runtime polymorphism of a high level class without virtual low-level methods would be appreciated!

Comment: Visitor pattern seems appropriate.

Comment: Can `MeshA` be `final` class ?

Comment: You can always call virtual functions non-virtually. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Jarod42 Reminding myself of visitor and learning what `final` is now, thanks, I'll comment again soon.  Edit: yes, each of the derived `MeshX::cell_centroid()` methods could be `final`.  First I've heard of it so I don't know what that gains me, doing more research.

Comment: It isn't clear why you are concerned about templated code while being OK with heavily inlined non-template code. Where's the difference?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not totally against templated code, but the difference in this case is where the inline/template is.  In the inline'd version, the Mesh methods are inlined, but in Idea2, the templates are in user code, which is much harder to debug.  I'm not ruling it out as an option, just trying to weigh pros/cons.

Comment: Again, what are practical differences between a library of templated code and a library of non-templated code, provided that both are 100% inlined, from user's and developer's perspective? Off hand I can think of compilstion times and compiler error messages, and that's about it.

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but that isn't the comparison made here.  The comparison here is between code inlined at lower levels in the dependency graph vs code templated at higher levels in the dependency graph.  In my (limited) experience, both of these things make it harder to debug, and so I try to avoid these things in high level, harder-to-unit-test, more complex places (when it is practical).

Comment: I would do something like "idea 1" but with a CRTP intermediate class, so all that intermediate code exists only once in the source code, and so there is minimal difference between the base class methods (that make virtual calls to sub functions) and intermediate functions that make CRTP inlined calls to sub functions (so the binary size vs. speed tradeoff is easy to tweak).

Comment: @JSF +1, the "right" implementation of Idea1 would definitely need CRTP to limit duplication in this middle layer.  At some level I might just need to start prototyping to see how much interface bloat Idea1 would result in.

Comment: hmmm... determien the type once with `dynamic_cast` ,casting the pointer to the right type,  moving the object to stack allocated object, call the method than once move the stack object back to the heap? evil solution but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I understood you correctly that mesh_ will always be either MeshA or MeshB and not a mix of them.

// typical user class

```
class User {
  User(Mesh* mesh) : mesh_(mesh) {}

  template<class dType>
  void evalFunction() {
    dType *myMesh = dynamic_cast<dType *>(mesh_);
    for (int c=0; c!=myMesh _->num_cells(); ++c) {
      double result = func(myMesh _->cell_centroid(c));
      ...
    }
  }
  void evalFunction() {
    if (dynamic_cast<MeshA *>(mesh_))
      evalFunction<MeshA>();
    if (dynamic_cast<MeshB *>(mesh_))
      evalFunction<MeshB>();
  }
}
```

`evalFunction` chooses either A or B template.

Alternatively

```
class User {
  User(Mesh* mesh) : mesh_(mesh) {}

  template<class dType>
  void evalFunction(dType *myMesh) {
    for (int c=0; c!=myMesh _->num_cells(); ++c) {
      double result = func(myMesh _->cell_centroid(c));
      ...
    }
  }
  void evalFunction() {
    MeshA *meshA = dynamic_cast<MeshA *>(mesh_);
    if (meshA)
      evalFunction<MeshA>(meshA);
    MeshB *meshB = dynamic_cast<MeshB *>(mesh_);
    if (meshB)
      evalFunction<MeshB>(meshB);
  }
}
```

Comment: That second dynamic cast (the one inside the templated evalFuncion) is pretty well redundant. A better solution would be to make the templated evalFunction take a pointer to dType as its sole argument, and pass in the downcast pointer.

Comment: @NirFriedman, yes, I've tried the other solution and it should be faster unless it inlines and the extra `dynamic_cast` disappears.

Comment: Thanks, this fleshes out what Idea 3 could look like, and makes that idea a lot more plausible in my mind.  I want to give this another day or two to see if anyone else has different thoughts, but will accept soon otherwise.